# Change number format to remove parentheses

Tags: vba, date, format, numbers, user-defined-functions

I have a short UDF which creates a time mark. The data it reads is in the following format: "(03/11/2004  16:00:00)".
The UDF only works without the parentheses i.e. "03/11/2004  16:00:00" so how can I get it to remove the parentheses (without overwriting the source data) or change the number format to what i need?

```
Function TimeMark(xtime, delay)
    Dim H As Integer, M As Integer, S As Integer, D As Integer, Mon As Integer, Y As Integer
    xtime = xtime + delay / 24
    S = 0
    M = 0
    H = Hour(xtime)
    D = Day(xtime)
    Mon = Month(xtime)
    Y = Year(xtime)
    TimeMark = TimeSerial(H, M, S) + DateSerial(Y, Mon, D)

End Function
```

Comment: Replace the ( and ) with nothing see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function

Comment: Important notes for your function: Declare the type for the input data. E.g. If you're hoping to get Strings, declare `xtime As String`.  If you want to make a modification to the input data without actually changing the value in the variable given to you, declare the parameter as `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`. This means your function will make a copy of the data when accepting the input, and it wont have the ability to edit the original. Final suggestion: `ByVal xtime As String, ByVal delay As Double`

Comment: As a side note, this UDF is almost the same as using `CDate` and `DateAdd`.  After removing the parentheses,`DateAdd("h", delay, CDate(xtime))` to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Combine input from @CHill60 and @ToddlesonA and you have a one-liner:

```vb
Public Function TimeMark(ByVal xtime As String, ByVal delay As Double) As Date

    TimeMark = CDate(Replace(Replace(xtime, "(", ""), ")", "")) + delay / 24

End Function
```

Comment: Hi gustav, thanks for your input here!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mid()` to remove the parentheses and DateValue to extract the date value.

```
' This function takes a string representing a time and a delay (in hours), 
' and returns a time mark that is the original time plus the delay.
Function TimeMark(xtime As String, delay As Double)

    Dim Result As Date ' Holds the result date
    
    ' Extract the time from the string by removing the first and last character, 
    ' and convert it to a date/time type. The assumption here is that xtime 
    ' contains a time string enclosed in additional characters (e.g., brackets).
    ' If xtime is "(12:30)", then Result becomes "12:30".
    Result = Mid(xtime, 2, Len(xtime) - 2)
    
    ' Add the delay to the Result time. 
    ' The delay is divided by 24 to convert it from hours to a fraction of a day, 
    ' because in VBA, the integer part of a Date variable represents days.
    ' The Result is the new time mark that is the original time plus the delay.
    TimeMark = Result + delay / 24

End Function
```

Comment: Hi TinMan, thanks for your input here!